# How do I use range breaks and scattergl in the same plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have this plot-

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattergl(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.Measure)), row = 1, col = 1)
    
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)
```

The code works fine when I remove the range-breaks, but stops working when I add them in.

Is it possible to use range breaks and scatter gl in the same plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [official documentation](https://plotly.com/python/webgl-vs-svg/) *range breaks on time-series axes are not yet supported* in the WebGL-powered version of certain SVG-powered trace types, e.g. scattergl (plotly version 5.10.0). So to make it work we have to switch to the `go.Scatter`.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Dummy data
s = pd.date_range(end=pd.Timestamp('2022-08-27'), periods=100, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':s, 'Measure': s.day})

# Plot
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    # replace Scattergl with the Scatter object
    go.Scatter(x=df.Date, y=df.Measure))

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]), # skip weekends
    ],
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1,
                 label="1m",
                 step="month",
                 stepmode="backward")
        ])
    ),
    rangeslider=dict(
        visible=True
    ),
    type="date"
)

fig.show()
```

[image]